# Result of IF Statements is not showing correctly

Tags: php

any idea what can be wrong with my code?
if value of variable is correct and output is correct, there is showing that it is incorrect.

Then after trying multiple times the result is correct, everything is perfect.

After that I am trying my code again, when I click refresh, old results is staying.

Input Is not matching with value variable, but there still showing old result that it is correct.

Thanks for all help

Nancy

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Printing Quotes</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='container'>
        <header>
            <h1 id="title">Who said this quote?</h1>
        </header>
        <section>
            <?php
                $quote="These aren't the droids you're looking for.";
                $author = 'Kenobi';

                echo "<div id='question'>
                        <h2>$quote</h2>
                      </div>";

            ?>
                <form action="" method="POST">
                    <input id='input' type="text" name="author" placeholder="Enter your answer">
                </form>
        </section>
        <section>
            <?php
                if(isset($_POST['author']) == $author){

                    echo "<div id='correct'> Correct!!!</div>";

                    echo "<br>";

                    echo 
                    "<div id='quote'>{$author} says: \" $quote \" </div>";

                    echo 'match';        
                    echo '<br>';
                    echo 'Variable value:'. $author;
                    echo '<br>';
                    echo 'User Input:'. $_POST['author'];

                }

                else {
                    echo "not match";
                    echo '<br>';
                    echo 'Variable value:'. $author;
                    echo '<br>';
                    echo 'User Input: '. $_POST['author'];

                }
            ?>
        </section>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Zxx0.jpg)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I`ve understood you currently, if you send form to self php file use $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] in form action then check

```
if(isset($_POST['author']) && $_POST['author'] == $author)
```

Answer (score 4):

`isset($_POST['author'])` is a boolean check. You are comparing TRUE|FALSE against the contents of `$author`. I suspect you mean to put `if(isset($_POST['author']) && $_POST['author'] == $author)`

Comment: thanks it works!!! I will remember isset($_POST['ANYTHING']) is comparing ONLY TRUE OR FALSE